# Does pytest have info on which marker expression was given

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Does pytest context has member which holds the given argument to "-m" flag ?
for example in the command `$python3 -m pytest -m "regression and not unit"`
is it possible to get the info on `regression and not unit` from within pytest context ?